# How to SELECT all names that consist of 2 words

Tags: sql, database

How to use LIKE to search for all names that consist of 2 any words.

Comment: Please tag the DBMS and share your code and sample result you expect. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you mean 2 or more words, or exactly 2 words?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming words are separated by a space:

```
where name like '% %' and name not like '% % %'
```

Comment: nice and simple for the OP question.. other options are REGEX check for the pattern, and a count of the number of space characters = 1